# Adding a pagefooter to custAccountStatementExt that will appear for every customer

Tags: report, dynamics-ax-2009

I have been asked to modify the Customer account statement (custAccountStatementExt) report in Dynamics AX 2009. I need to add a page footer to each statement showing an overdue balance at different time intervals (ie 30, 60, 90 etc days overdue).

I have written display methods to calculate these values and I have added a reportFooter section to the report but it does not show.

If I add the code to a report Epilogue it works fine so I am reasonably confident that the code is correct.

It seems as if the page footers are turned on and off as required for displaying of the giro sections. I have tried commenting out all the disable page footer code but my footer still will not show.

Is there a way to get this footer to display on every page regardless of the giro printing?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to override the method "executeSection()" in that section (pageFooter). Within that method, you would need to figure out whether or not you want to show it or not, and if you want to show it, you'll call "super()". Otherwise you won't.

Take a look at the report "SalesInvoice" and the PageFooter named "PrepaidTotalsEuro". Look at the "executeSection()"-method. Don't get confused by the boolean variable, it is there to make sure the footer is only printed on the first page.

Comment: Hi thanks, I had just tried something similar to this before I read this post. I override the execureSection, put in an info message and a breakpoint but the code is never hit at runtime.